# B2C - How to override sign up now link (custom policy)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I used this documentation to override a **forgot password** link in **singInOrSignup** custom policy, and it works perfectly :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

How can I please do the same things for **Sign up now** link to redirect to another custom policy that I created before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doc never sent the user to another policy for password reset. It just sends the user to a technical profile within the same policy. You can’t send the user to another policy through configuration of the custom policy.

You can rewrite the link using JavaScript using page customisation. Send the user to myapp.com/signup, do not link directly to another B2C policy,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how we would rewrite that link based on the page that redirected to adb2c?  For example we have dev-app.mydomain.com and test-app.mydomain.com (etc) all using the same policy that need to rewrite to {app}/signup.

Comment: You could use javascript to parse the current URL - which will contain the redirectURI (it will be specific to the app the user came from), and then use that to build the link.